# rsync ssh to ssh to local

Tags: ssh, rsync

Is it possible to perform a rsync to backup files from a server passing by an another server by ssh. And I have to use port 23 from local to server1.

So :

```
         ssh           ssh -p 23
server2 -----> server1 ------------> local.
```

I ask that because I cannot perform a rsync directly on server2.

Thanks in advace

EDIT :

I resolve myself the problem :) :

```
rsync -e "ssh -X -p 23 user@server1 ssh" user@server2:/path/to/file /path/local
```

Comment: nice. post it as an answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to the inverse path :

```
                     ssh             ssh 
some local directory -----> server1 -----> server2 .
```

both ssh need password to connect.

I tried that :

```
rsync local_dir -e "ssh -X user1@server1 ssh" user2@server2:/path/to/dir
```

I entered the first password (for server2). Then password for user1. And this error arrives :

```
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,password).
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(605) [sender=3.0.9]
```

Any idea?

> Edit : Answered myself again but using a scp instaed :

```
scp -rp -oProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p user1@server1" localDirectoryToTransfer user2@server2:/path/to/dir
```